# cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 1771077

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dummy-variable, valueerror

I have a dataframe (size : (1771077, 38) ) named "combi".
when i try to run the following code:

```
dum = ['Date_ID', 'Distribution_Type','Fixed_CostFactor','Product_Description','Order_ID','Quantity','Amount','SalesMgr_Name', 'Sales_Type', 'Product_Description','Product_Category', 'Product_Group', 'Brand', Unit_of_Measure', 'Pack_Type','Cost_Price', 'Sales_Price', PlantName','City_Name','Population', 'Customer_Name', 'Customer_Since',     'Industry', 'Customer_Group','Month_Name', 'Quarter_No']

dummies = pd.get_dummies(combi[dum])
```

It gives this error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-1227d2ff4df6> in <module>()
      4        'Industry', 'Customer_Group','Month_Name', 'Quarter_No']
      5 
----> 6 dummies = pd.get_dummies(combi[dum])
      7 dummies.columns

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.pyc in get_dummies(data, prefix, prefix_sep, dummy_na, columns, sparse, drop_first)
   1206             dummy = _get_dummies_1d(data[col], prefix=pre, prefix_sep=sep,
   1207                                     dummy_na=dummy_na, sparse=sparse,
-> 1208                                     drop_first=drop_first)
   1209             with_dummies.append(dummy)
   1210         result = concat(with_dummies, axis=1)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.pyc in _get_dummies_1d(data, prefix, prefix_sep, dummy_na, sparse, drop_first)
   1218                     sparse=False, drop_first=False):
   1219     # Series avoids inconsistent NaN handling
-> 1220     codes, levels = _factorize_from_iterable(Series(data))
   1221 
   1222     def get_empty_Frame(data, sparse):

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    246             else:
    247                 data = _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy,
--> 248                                        raise_cast_failure=True)
    249 
    250                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   3027             raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
   3028         else:
-> 3029             subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)
   3030 
   3031     # This is to prevent mixed-type Series getting all casted to

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.pyc in _asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype)
    378             except ValueError:
    379                 # we have a list-of-list
--> 380                 result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]
    381 
    382     return result

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 1771077
```

but when i run this, it doesnt give any error:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(combi)
```

can someone please tell me what is going wrong and how do i fix this? I wish to work with just a subset of the original columns.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same error while trying to sparse my categorical data using get_dummies(), the issue was I had duplicate column names when I removed them then I didn't got this error again.

Hope it helps someone who comes here with same problem.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In you dum list, you seem to have missed a few single quotes. For example, Unit_of_Measure and PlantName. Can you fix it and try again?

```
dum=['Date_ID',
'Distribution_Type',
'Fixed_CostFactor',
'Product_Description',
'Order_ID',
'Quantity',
'Amount',
'SalesMgr_Name',
'Sales_Type',
'Product_Description',
'Product_Category',
'Product_Group',
'Brand',
Unit_of_Measure',
'Pack_Type',
'Cost_Price',
'Sales_Price',
PlantName',
'City_Name',
'Population',
'Customer_Name',
'Customer_Since',
'Industry',
'Customer_Group',
'Month_Name',
'Quarter_No']
```

May be use the code below, you can identify which column is causing the problem.

```
for c in dum:
    print('column: {}, len: {}'.format(c, len(pd.get_dummies(df[c]))))
```

Comment: hi allen, That is weird. in my code there is no such mistake. I copied and pasted it here and it shows missing quotes. Anyway, i checked my code on my notebook, all quotes are in place. So that isn't a problem i guess.

Comment: It ran for the first 2 columns, then i got this MemoryError.

column: Date_ID, len: 1771077
column: Distribution_Type, len: 1771077

MemoryErrorTraceback (most recent call last)

Comment: Seems your machine has run out of memory. Will this work? dummies = pd.get_dummies(combi, columns=dum)

Comment: When i run for the whole set of columns, it works fine. But when i choose to work on a subset, it runs out of memory. Doesnt make sense to me. Also, am running on a hadoop cluster and can increase the nodes.

and no allen even _dummies = pd.get_dummies(combi, columns=dum)_ gave the same MemoryError

Comment: Have you checked the results when you do it with the entire df? One more thing to try: df2 = combi[dum].copy()
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df2)

Comment: Yes i have checked the results using "dummies.columns" gave me around 4k columns. And Yes, I  have tried that method as well. Didnt work. Same old ValueError

Comment: I guess since you can do it with the while df and the results are correct, you could just slice the columns you need from the results.

Comment: The thing is, i am gonna probbaly run PCA on this after that. since i need to feed it to linear regression model. and only some of the columns are needed, others are just redundant fields